# adding an image to a pin's info window (Google maps)

Tags: ios, google-maps

is it possible to add images to a google map pin's info window? i want to display a picture when the user taps the pin at a specified location. in Google's maps API i can only change the marker (pin) icon and thus replace the marker with another image. however, i want to be able to display the imag with the name of the place in the info window that appears when the user taps the marker.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it inside a

```
infowindow.setContent('<div><img src="rute.jpg" /></div>');
infowindow.open(map,marker);
```

I hope it helps.

Check out the google maps API documentation too, there's a lot of infomration.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: sorry bro i'm working on an ios app. didn't help. but yes i'll make sure to check the documentation. thank you!